# Unable to save NodeEntity having a @RelatedTo Outgoing Direction with another node

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j

I am using `Spring Boot` and `Neo4J 2.1.8` ,and have created two `NodeEntities` Parent and Child.
The parent class is

```
    @NodeEntity
    public class Parent{

        @GraphId
        @Indexed(indexName = "id", indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT)
        private Long id;

        @RelatedTo(type=RelationType.IS_RELATED,direction=Direction.OUTGOING)
        @Fetch
        private Set<Child> children;


    }
```

and the child class is

```
@NodeEntity
public class Child{
        @GraphId
    private Long id;

    private String name;
}
```

The `parentRepo` and `childRepo` class both extends `GraphRepository`

Now when a create a parent with a child object set in it and call `parentRepo.save(parent)`.The parent and child entities are created along with there relationship.

Now the problem statement is :

When an parent entity is already created and I do this

```
Child child= new Child()
...............
Parent parent=parentRepo.retriveParent(id);
parent.getChildren().add(child);
parentRepo.save(parent);
```

The following error is coming :-

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:149)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.UserAgent$1.handle(UserAgent.java:68)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:670)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.put(WebResource.java:523)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestRequest.put(ExecutingRestRequest.java:155)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPIImpl.setPropertiesOnEntity(RestAPIImpl.java:633)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.entity.RestEntity.flush(RestEntity.java:189)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I got it.I don't have to call `parentRepo.save(parent)`
What I did is

```
childRepo.save(child);
Parent parent=parentRepo.retriveParent(id);
parent.getChildren().add(child);
```

The Node and relationship was automatically updated .No need to explicitly call `parentRepo.save()`